# Extreme CPU usage when ploting using rxplot and rxbag tools

Tags: ros, rxplot, cpu, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

For some reason when I plot data using rxgraph or rxbag tools, the CPU usage explodes.

For example :
I trying to plot some fields of a topic that consist of 20 numerical fields and published on rate of 10Hz (not a high rate for my understanding).
when I attempt to plot at the same time 10 different graphs, the CPU usage jumps to over 90%.
The CPU usage not really improves even if I record and play a bag file.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this phenomenon ? Or suggest a way to deal with this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55814/extreme-cpu-usage-when-ploting-using-rxplot-and-rxbag-tools/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxgraph is pretty old and has degraded over time. I would suggest checking out rqt if you are using ROS Fuerte or Groovy. RQT is much better maintained at this point in time.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0